# Input loses focus when triggering v-if

Tags: vue.js

I got an input field:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2" :value="valueHours" @input="calculateTimes($event)" @blur="updateValueHours($event)">
```

And a list:

```
 <div v-if="open" ... >
   <div v-for="..." >
        list rendered here
```

When typing inside the input field I compute values that shall be highlighted inside the list:

```
        const calculateTimes = async (evt) => {
            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

            var highlightIndex = null,
                iterator = 0;

            while (highlightIndex === null && iterator < props.options.length) {
                var time = new Date(props.options[iterator].select_value).getHours()
                
                if (time.toString().includes(evt.target.value)) {
                    highlightIndex = iterator;
                    hasFocus.value = iterator;

                    open.value = true;
                    
                    await checkIfListElementIsRendered(`elem-${iterator}`)
                    scrollToFocusedElement();
                }

                iterator++;
            }
        }
```

The problem occurs when `open.value` is set to `true`. The input seems to lose the focus leading to the `:value="valueHours"` overwriting the input with it's current empty state. Just pre-filling the value (valueHours) doesn't solve the problem. Also re-focusing the input leads to buggy behavior. Why is it that toggling the list with v-if removes the focus from the input field?

Comment: I would suspect the `scrollToFocusedElement()` function.

Comment: Your code is not complete to analyse the problem. What happens in the `checkIfListElementIsRendered()` and `scrollToFocusedElement()`?

Comment: @Tolbxela The functions  `checkIfListElementIsRendered` and `scrollToFocusedElement` don't matter at all. even if I just vall `open.value = true` and delete the rest of the code the problem occurs.

Comment: Consider to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you please tell what `hasFocus` variable is doing?

Comment: This is the [minimal example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: When you type in a single letter in the input field, the component rerenders and the input value remains the same as it did before (empty).  Additional typed letters show up correctly

Comment: It was so easy. I had suspect on your `:value` starting from the beginning, but wasn't sure about.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply set `valueHours` inside the `calculateTimes`

```
const calculateTimes = (event) => {
  valueHours.value = event.target.value;
  open.value = true;
};
```

Fixed [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

or use `v-model` with your input field instead of value binding.

```
  <input
    v-model="valueHours"
    type="text"
    @input="calculateTimes"
    @blur="updateValueHours"
  />
```

[SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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) with `v-model`

**Explanation**

If you use :`value` binding, the value of `valueHours` will not be updated by the input, since it is one-way bound.
And then, when Vue refreshes DOM after `open.value = true` the input gets the initial value of `valueHours` again.

Check the Vue Documentation on how the [Form Input Bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html) and `v-model` works.

Comment: Yea, I know about the two way binding. But I simply can't use it in this case cause of other effects it needs to serve. I also tried the first method you mentioned but it didn't fix the issue. Guess I need to look for other side effects of my code. Thanks tho.